# Does the Synaptic Download script download the entire dependency tree of an app?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-managers

Does the download script (created by the "Generate Download Script" option) of the Synaptic package manager download each and every dependency on an application's dependency tree or does it only download those dependencies that were not already installed on the machine the script was generated in?

If the latter case, then how can I configure it to download the entire dependency tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synaptic will generate a downloaded script to download the package and its dependencies.

**NB: I am using debian stretch to give you an example ( please use the generated script on your Ubuntu machine)**

There is a sample script (to download `wicd`) generated by synaptic package manager:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -c http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-4_all.deb
wget -c http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-4_all.deb
wget -c http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-4_all.deb
wget -c http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wicd/wicd_1.7.4+tb2-4_all.deb
```

to list the dependencies of `wicd` package run : `apt-cache depends wicd` :

```
wicd
  Dépend: wicd-daemon
 |Dépend: wicd-gtk
 |Dépend: wicd-curses
 |Dépend: wicd-cli
  Dépend: <wicd-client>
    wicd-cli
    wicd-curses
    wicd-gtk
```

Comment: So does it mean "all dependencies" or "only the dependencies unavailable"?

Comment: @user2873330 it will generate the downloaded link for the missing dependencies , (if the dependencies is already installed the download link will not be generated)